# CPU is limited to 0.8 Ghz after both changing the hard drive and removing the battery

Tags: windows, cpu

My laptop is a Dell i7-4600 with 2.7 Ghz and I have both upgraded its hard drive to 1TB and removed its battery because it was broken.

After installing Windows, I saw my system is very laggy and my CPU is limited to 0.8GHz. Now I want to know which driver or unplugged battery made that. I have checked and updated the BIOS.

What can I do?

Comment: What is the *model number* of your laptop? When the CPU frequency is limited it is a sign of either not enough power, or not enough cooling (to protect itself from overheating). When you opened it to change the hard drive or battery, it's possible that you have disconnected or damaged the cooling system in some way. Forgetting to reconnect something before reassembling the cover is a simple explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

*Replace the battery. If it is defective, get a new one and install it. A laptop requires a battery installed to run properly.* Dell laptops are able to function without the battery plugged in, but this does not rule out battery not plugged in as a possible cause of the system being extremely slow after battery removal. It could also be caused by hardware, software, malware, etc.

#### Windows

*Perform general troubleshooting in Windows* <sup>[source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/system-extremely-slow-after-battery-removal/36f41e27-9be3-4f5d-ab17-ea688dc96756)</sup> to identify and resolve the problem.

> Try a System Restore back to a point in time *before* the problem began.
>   Here's the procedure:
>   https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-system-restore/.
>
> Be sure to check the box to show more than 5 days of restore points.
>   If the first attempt fails, then try an earlier point or two. NOTE:
>   You will have to reinstall any software and updates you installed
>   between now and the restore point, but you can use Windows Update for
>   the updates. Use the recovery disk if the system prompt doesn't work.
>   The recovery disk works a bit different from the above procedures, but
>   if you follow the prompts from the System Restore menu option with the
>   above information you should be able to restore with no problems.
>
> If the System Restore doesn't work, do a Startup Repair by booting to
>   the genuine Windows Installation Disk (or one you can borrow
>   from anyone) or from a Recovery Disk. Here's the procedure:
>   https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7728/. 
>   To boot to the disk you may need to change the BIOS to make the optical drive
>   first in the boot sequence. To do that wait for the screen that tells
>   you the F keys (F1-F12) to press to access the boot menu or boot setup. Press it
>   quickly. Make the changes, save your work, and exit. Put the disk in the
>   drive and reboot. When prompted, press any key to boot from the disk.
>
> If you don't have either disk, you can make a bootable Recovery Disk
>   using
>   https://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/ along
>   with burning software like:
>   [https://www.snapfiles.com/get/active-isoburner.html](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/active-isoburner.html) and,
>   of course, a blank CD/DVD.
>
> If that doesn't work, try to boot into safe mode (repeatedly press the
>   F8 key while booting and go to Safe mode with networking – or do so
>   from the command prompt on the disk). Then check some of your
>   system files:
>
> Go to Start / All Programs / Accessories / Command prompt and right
>   click on command prompt and click Run as Administrator (you can skip
>   this step if using the disk).
>
> If using the disk, `cd` to `C:\Windows\System32`. Type `sfc /scannow`
>   and Enter and let it run. It will scan and try to fix some of your
>   system files.
>
> While in Command Prompt, type `chkdsk /f /r` and Enter and let it run.
>   It will want to schedule itself to run at the next restart. Answer yes
>   and then reboot to run the program.  It will scan and try to fix any
>   corruption or bad sectors on your hard drive and mostly remove that as
>   a potential cause.
>
> If that doesn't work, then please post any repeating error messages
>   from the Event Viewer concerning startup or shutdown (Start / Control
>   Panel / Administrative Tools / Event Viewer – or typing `eventvwr`
>   from the command prompt starting from `C:\Windows\System32`). Here's
>   how to use Event Viewer:
>   https://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/75433.
>   Look in the System and the Application section.
>
> You may be infected with malware. Try to run anti-malware programs (in
>   safe mode with networking if necessary). To fix this problem (if it is
>   a problem) download, install, and run the following two programs:
>   [https://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php) and
>   [https://www.safer-networking.org/en/index.html](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/index.html).
>   You may also want to try the free version of Panda Antivirus.
>
> Before downloading Panda Antivirus, uninstall whatever antivirus program
>   you are currently using (because installing and running two at the
>   same time can cause conflicts,one freezes, and all sorts of problems).
>   Once you've uninstalled your current AV program, download, install,
>   update, and scan using Panda Antivirus. Once complete, uninstall
>   Panda Antivirus and reinstall your current AV program (unless you decide 
>   to switch). You may also want to try Microsoft Security Essentials 
>   (with the same caveat that only *one* AV program can be installed and
>   running on your system at any one time). You may also want to try the
>   free Avira at: [https://www.free-av.com/](http://www.free-av.com/) and
>   Avast at: [https://www.avast.com/index](http://www.avast.com/index). 
>   Reboot after completing all the scans.
>
> If that doesn't work, try a clean boot [https://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135).
>   If the problem goes away then it's just a matter of tracking down the
>   culprit causing the problem. Follow the procedures in the article. 
>   Once found, delete, remove, deactivate, or uninstall it. Once done be
>   sure to reset Windows back to normal status as explained in the
>   procedures. If the problem occurs in clean mode then just restore the
>   system to normal status and reboot - this solution is not going to
>   work.
>
> Boot into Safe mode with networking and see if the problem occurs
>   there.  Either result helps to narrow down the search for the cause.
>
> You may be having troubles with your device drivers. Go to Device
>   Manager by going to start / search box and type *device manager* and
>   Enter and then double-click on the program icon that appears. Check
>   each device for a red x, yellow ! or white ?. These identify devices
>   with problems (probably drivers, but also conflicts or something
>   else). Click on each for further details and troubleshooting tips  If
>   you need to get drivers (and you should do so for all devices when you
>   you have time to do so  - they may help in ways beyond just resolving
>   this problem), do so from the computer vendor or device manufacturer
>   (NOT from Microsoft Updates). In fact, you should turn off automatic
>   driver updates from Windows Update. Proceed to get the drivers:
>   and install them through Device Manager.
>
> Test your RAM at [https://www.memtest.org/](http://www.memtest.org/). If it fails, test
>   each chip individually to find those that are bad and replace them. If
>   it passes, the RAM is probably OK.

---

#### Linux

Troubleshooting in Linux is a lot different from troubleshooting in Windows. Boot any Linux distro from a live USB. Don't boot from a DVD, boot from a live USB so you can install whatever diagnostic tools you need on the USB from your Linux distro's default repository. Ubuntu's repositories have whatever tools you need without entering into complications with downloading third-party software.

If there's anything wrong with your computer's hardware it will usually print a boot message on the screen when the computer is booting. On a fast computer a few pages of boot messages passes by in only one or two seconds, so you'll need a smartphone to take screen photos. After a while using Linux you'll get so proficient at understanding boot messages that you can study the screen photos and then head out to a computer store for the right replacement part.

Once you've booted into the Linux desktop the diagnostic tools are interactive. Get a sheet of paper and write down whatever steps you followed, so you can backtrack and undo a step if it didn't work. Plug a USB flash drive into the computer so you can save screenshots on the USB if you need to. There's a few screenshot tools to choose from. The default screenshot tool in Ubuntu is too simple. I like a more full-featured screenshot tool that lets you write and draw on the screenshot. Linux is open source software and it gives you a lot more information than Windows, so you need to have good tools to save the diagnostic data you collected so you don't miss out on anything.

Comment: To anyone who wants to comment, please edit this answer instead of commenting about it. I'm OK with drastic editorial changes. I want to collaborate on this answer so it won't become obsolete.